# openbsd 6 nginx php 404

Tags: php, nginx, openbsd

I have problem to configure php, `index.html` works fine but `index.php` don't work: `404`

**1.** I can't find recent doc about openbsd 6 and nginx, all tutorials are wrong with command

**2.** I installed mysql but also doesn't work, so at the end, I don't know which package to install

**3.** this freaking error with php

here is my **nginx.conf:**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files      $uri $uri/ =404;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather complex. I will take it step by step:

Making php work in nginx under OpenBSD requires:

```
# pkg_add -v php-5.6.23p0
# rcctl enable php56_fpm
# rcctl start php56_fpm
```

Running mariadb-server after installation needs the following actions:

```
# /usr/local/bin/mysql_install_db
# rcctl enable mysqld
# rcctl start mysqld
```

Adjust /etc/my.cnf to put and connect to the MariaDB socket

```
[client]
socket = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
socket = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
```

3. the nginx config should then contain a section similar to the following, where you have to set separately two locations and in the main section set the index.php to be an acceptable index:

   ```
   server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  test;
   location / {
       root   /var/www/htdocs/sites/test;
       index  index.php index.html index.htm;
   }
   location ~ \.php$ {
       include /usr/pkg/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $documentroot$fastcgi_script_name;
       }
   }
   ```

For every more complex package there is always a good readme in:

```
/usr/local/share/doc/pkg-readmes/*
```

And of course connecting PHP to MYSQL needs some packages too, so depending on your choice one or more of these three:

```
# pkg_add -v php-mysqli-5.6.23p0 php-mysql-5.6.23p0 php-pdo_mysql-5.6.23p0
```

And then enabling the backend in /etc/php.ini

Comment: oh really thank you, I havent got a notification.
I fixed my errors, it was not pathed to fastcgi